# Get True/False boolean list of row in pandas dataframe out of condition

Tags: pandas, list, filtering, boolean-logic

I am working with several Pandas DataFrames and I need the following filtering:

[image]

Suppose I get a list like

```
L=['EP6','EP3','EP2']
```

I need to get the following vector of a row:

for row concept 1 True where columns index is in L, False where not.

I am trying:

```
# D being the DataFrame
L=['EP6', 'EP3','EP2']
[True for ind in D.columns if ind in L ]
```

But only get [True,True,True]
I need the complete list like:

```
desire_result=[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0]
```

Note: be aware that the 1 in the desire result do not have anything to do with the 1 the Dataframe is populate with.

Thanks

Comment: It should be `[ ind in L for ind in D.columns]`.

Comment: works. This is a great comprehension

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You here made a *filter* where you yield `True`, given `ind in L`, and otherwise, you do not yield an element.

You here want to perform a *mapping*. You can still use list comprehension, but you should put the condition in the yield part:

```
[ind in L for ind in D.columns]
```

or if you want integers:

```
[int(ind in L) for ind in D.columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

We have `isin` in `pandas`

```
D.columns.isin(L)
```